# Reposition background-image according to display size and unknown margins

Tags: html, css

did this for my homepage and wanted to background image content to be the middle of the image as the display size decreases (right now it slides the content of the image to the left). Thought of media query but Client only allows for one add-on of CSS, not different stylesheet files.

Also, although stated * margin= 0; padding=0 a margin appears on my smartphone (Iphone 6) and want it to be clear full screen as in desktop. Make browser pretty small to see if from laptop/desktop.

It has to be CSS ONLY since my client (Smugmug) only allows for blocks of css and html on it, no javascript or whatsoever. Also adds its own CSS to the page so I can post the link if needed.

Any idea for the dynamic positioning of the images and the margins? Thanks!

```css
html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding; 0;
  }

  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }

  a {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #business-top {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height:50vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-image : url(https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-2KvXfrk/0/X3/_MG_9556-X3.jpg
  );
      background-size:cover;
  }

  #business-button {
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    height: 3em;
    width: 12em;
    background-color: #2B2A2A;
    border: .2em solid #ff7600;
    border-radius: 1.8em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
  }


  #logo-separator {
    text-align: center;
    top: calc( 50%-height_of_separator)px;
  }

  .separator {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0;
    flex: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ff7600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff7600;
  }

  #logo {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -75px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
  }

  #photography-bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height:50vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image : url(https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-gPg5QBt/0/X3/_DSC5313-X3.jpg
  );
    background-size:cover;
  }

  #photography-button {
    height: 3em;
    width: 12em;
    background-color: #2B2A2A;
    border: .2em solid #ff7600;
    border-radius: 1.8em;
    margin: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    color: #ff7600;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2.2em
  }

  #business-top,
  #photography-bottom {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    min-height: 200px;
  }

  #business-top a,
  #photography-bottom a {
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="business-top">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="business-button">
      <h1>PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="logo-separator">
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-CsMnM3R/0/Th/800x800-round-Th.png"> </div>
</div>

<div id="photography-bottom">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="photography-button">
      <h1>BUSINESS</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI mistake here  `padding; 0;` should be `padding: 0;`

Comment: Sorry, but don't see the difference... Spacing or something?

Comment: this `;`to `:` after `padding`

Comment: hahahahahaha, damn! Thanks, noob things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use background-position if you want to position a background image.

```css
html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  h1 {
    margin: 0;
  }

  a {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  #business-top {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height:50vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center center; 
    background-image : url(https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-2KvXfrk/0/X3/_MG_9556-X3.jpg
  );
      background-size:cover;
  }

  #business-button {
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    height: 3em;
    width: 12em;
    background-color: #2B2A2A;
    border: .2em solid #ff7600;
    border-radius: 1.8em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align:center;
  }


  #logo-separator {
    text-align: center;
    top: calc( 50%-height_of_separator)px;
  }

  .separator {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0;
    flex: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ff7600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ff7600;
  }

  #logo {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: -75px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
  }

  #photography-bottom {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height:50vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-position: center center; 
    background-image : url(https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-gPg5QBt/0/X3/_DSC5313-X3.jpg
  );
    background-size:cover;
  }

  #photography-button {
    height: 3em;
    width: 12em;
    background-color: #2B2A2A;
    border: .2em solid #ff7600;
    border-radius: 1.8em;
    margin: auto;
  }

  h1 {
    color: #ff7600;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 2.2em
  }

  #business-top,
  #photography-bottom {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    min-height: 200px;
  }

  #business-top a,
  #photography-bottom a {
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="business-top">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="business-button">
      <h1>PHOTOGRAPHY</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div id="logo-separator">
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div id="logo"><img src="https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-CsMnM3R/0/Th/800x800-round-Th.png"> </div>
</div>

<div id="photography-bottom">
  <a href="www.lluisballbe.smugmug.com">
    <div id="photography-button">
      <h1>BUSINESS</h1>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot of margins in Iphone 6]

Comment: Great! That was it. Thanks :) Any tip about thouse margins? Don't know why they came up if statted 0...

Comment: I couldn't see the margins yet in a narrow browser window and haven't been able to find out how to run the code snippet when accessing this page on an iphone.

Comment: So rare... Uploading a screenshot of my phone to the lowest part of the post!

Comment: There's a CSS-Rule which is loaded at a breakpoint of 670px which adds this: `margin: 0 12px !important; padding: 12px 0 !important;`  
    
You can see this in a web inspector when you examine the div with class `sm-page-widget-content`

Comment: Damn... That's my client inherited CSS... Thanks, could not find where it was at!

Answer (score 1):

add this css property to your both divs

```
background-position: center;
```

as example like this

```
 #business-top {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    height:50vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-image : url(https://lluisballbe.smugmug.com/Assets-for-website/i-2KvXfrk/0/X3/_MG_9556-X3.jpg);
    background-position: center;

  }
```

do like this for your other div and try.

Comment: Solved! Thanks @Graham :)